# Access last elements of inner multiindex level in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, multi-index

In a `multi index` pandas dataframe I want to access the **last** element of the second index for all values of the first index. The number of levels in the second index vary depending on the value of the first index. I went through the [pandas multi index documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) but could not find anything that does that.

For example, for the data frame below:

```
arrays = [ ['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo',   'qux'],
           ['one', 'two', 'one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'one']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7, 3), index=index, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df
                 A         B         C
first second
bar   one     0.289163 -0.464633 -0.060487
      two     0.224442  0.177609  2.156436
baz   one    -0.262329 -0.248384  0.925580
foo   one     0.051350  0.452014  0.206809
      two     2.757255 -0.739196  0.183735
      three  -0.064909 -0.963130  1.364771
qux   one    -1.330857  1.881588 -0.262170
```

I want to get:

```
                 A         B         C
first second
bar   two     0.224442  0.177609  2.156436
baz   one    -0.262329 -0.248384  0.925580
foo   three  -0.064909 -0.963130  1.364771
qux   one    -1.330857  1.881588 -0.262170
```

The `dataframes` I am working with have over `10M` lines so I want to avoid explicit looping.

Comment: You could do `df.groupby(level='first').last()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`tail`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
print (df.groupby(level='first').tail(1))
                     A         B         C
first second                              
bar   two     0.053054 -0.555819  0.589998
baz   one    -0.868676  1.293633  1.339474
foo   three   0.407454  0.738872  1.811894
qux   one    -0.346014 -1.491270  0.446772
```

because [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) lost `level second`:

```
print (df.groupby(level='first').last())         
              A         B         C
first                              
bar    0.053054 -0.555819  0.589998
baz   -0.868676  1.293633  1.339474
foo    0.407454  0.738872  1.811894
qux   -0.346014 -1.491270  0.446772
```

Comment: Using the last command got me a `FutureWarning` stating that I should use a list instead

Comment: @Eulenfuchswiesel - What is your code exactly? Seems have `df.groupby(level='first')['col1','col2'].last()`, need `df.groupby(level='first')[['col1','col2']].last()`

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the issue! I added the parenthesis at the wrong position